# Adding a parent object with many child objects attached

Tags: swift, core-data

In Swift, I am trying to add one instance to Core Data of my parent entity, Workout every time my Save boolean is made true, with many split children entities associated with the singular parent entity. When I try to save, it makes one parent with all of the child entities (which I want), but then it creates an additional parent entity for each child object (which is what I do not want.) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsHCo.png)

I am expecting to have one parent entity with many child entities within it each time the onChange is run.

```swift
.onChange (of: Save) { newValue in
    if Save {
        let newWorkout = Workout(context: moc)
        newWorkout.id = UUID()
        newWorkout.url1 = url1
        newWorkout.ur12 = ur12
        newWorkout.title = titleLine
        newWorkout.dateCreated = Date()

        for splitItem in env.splitlist {
            let split = Split(context: moc)
            split.textName = splitItem.textName
            split.section = Int16 (splitItem.section)
            split.time1 = splitItem.timel
            split.time2 = splitItem.time2
            split.timeDif1 = splitItem.timeDif1
            split.timeDif2 = splitItem.timeDif2
            split.leftClick = splitItem.leftClick
            split.runningTime1 = Int64 (splitItem.runningTimel.value)
            split.runningTime2 = Int64 (splitItem.runningTime2.value)
            split.ifDifZero = splitItem.timeDifZero
            newWorkout. addToSplits(split)
        }
        try? moc.save() 
        print ("Workout entity saved:", newWorkout) 
        print ("Child splits:", newWorkout.splits!)

        bugger = true
        Save = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code as text.

Comment: That code only creates one `Workout`, so either (a) it's being run more times than you think, or (b) you're creating new `Workout` instances somewhere else. Core Data doesn't create them automatically, only your code can do that.